# Micrometer: No of active users in a system over time period?

Tags: java, spring-boot, prometheus, metrics

I have spring boot app which push metrics to Prometheus.

I want to track no of active users in system over predefined time. For this I publish user_id as a tag in Gauge metric as follows,

```
user_id{user_id="test-user-id-2"} 1.0
user_id{user_id="test-user-id-5"} 1.0
user_id{user_id="test-user-id-1"} 1.0
user_id{user_id="test-user-id-0"} 1.0
user_id{user_id="test-user-id-9"} 1.0
```

This system is internal have only about 100 users and we don't expect user count to grow. Unique user id is used as tag since we have same instance running in cluster and don't want a centralized location to keep this data. This is simple system designed to be stateless.

Now i want no of above metrics reported over time period. For example i want to get how many users are active in last 5m . I have tried with `rate` function but could not get desired result. Is there way I can get sum over certain time period on these metrics ? ( I have tried `sum_over_time` also but no luck )

Answer (score 1):

I will explain it in two steps to facilitate the understanding:

**First**: you can use the `count` together with the `by` functionality to group the `user_id` of your metric. Your metric is a bit confusing because you have the name of the metric equals to the name of the label. I will try to write your query and compare it with one of mine that I can check the result.

Here for instance I want to get the metric `http_server_requests_seconds_bucket` and group it by the label `pod`, then I count.

```
count(http_server_requests_seconds_bucket) by (pod)
```

for your metric it will be something like below, where your metric is the first `user_id`, you can group by the label `user_id`, and then you count:

```
count(user_id) by (user_id)
```

**Second**: in case you want to count for a predefined amount of time, then you have to use the `rate` functionality. Let's say you want for the last 5 minutes. I get the latest 5 minutes results using `rate(MU_METRIC)[5m]` and I group then by the label `pod` using the `by` keyword and then I count.

```
count by (pod) (rate(http_server_requests_seconds_bucket[5m]))
```

For your metric it will be something like below:

```
count by (user_id) (rate(user_id[5m]))
```

Examples of references can be found [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/examples/).

Comment: Thank you very much. This and examples helped a lot. But this give cumulative sum of metric. It always whole sum. What i want more like sliding window sum. For ex , for last 5m get the sum of user_counts. Let's say user logged in at time t1 ( using /login end point ). At each rest call he/she does, I will increment ( or write ) metric which belong to him using user_id as tag. If user not send any requests for 10m ( no api calls ), then in Prometheus side when i view user sum from now-5m time period that user should not be counted.

Comment: if I understood correctly you want a dynamic sliding window that you can see the changes of every 5 minutes for the past 1 hour. Using the query above you can see that on the graphical visualization.